# CKEditor image upload issue

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am having problem with CKEditor, I cannot upload the any images, I am getting this error `Invalid file. The file size is too big.` However, I increase the file size;

```
$config['ResourceType'][] = Array(
        'name' => 'Images',
        'url' => $baseUrl . 'images',
        'directory' => $baseDir . 'images',
        'maxSize' => 4024,
        'allowedExtensions' => 'bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png',
        'deniedExtensions' => '');
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is upload_max_filesize in php.ini set up correctly as well?

Comment: hmm post_max_size as well? Also I guess 4024 is actually 4k bytes. it's quite small no?

Comment: Yes, you were right, thanks I got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should try to upload images to one folder on server for that user and show a popup which will show all his images user can copy image location and paste in image URL field in CKEditor's image import popup or u can put URL of that image in that field using JavaScript when user selects it. this way images wont need to be uploaded more that once and its easy to handle uploads and no need to mess with CKEditor's code.